# Url action as attr does not work after publishing in IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list like below.

```
 Select type :

 @Html.DropDownList("MyTypes", new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem{ Text="OT", Value = "1" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="PT", Value = "2" },
},
      "Select Type",
      new { @onclick = "onDropdownChanged(this)" })
```

I also have a htmlactionlink below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Generate PDF for Employees", "GetEmployees", "CreatePDF", new { id = "admin" })
```

I want to pass the value of the dropdownlist to this url. What I have done is like below.

```
 function onDropdownChanged(element) {     

        var selectedValue = $("#MyTypes").val();
        var link = $("#admin"); 
        link.attr("href", "/CreatePDF/GetEmployees/" + selectedValue);
  }
```

And I am successfully able to pass 1 or 2 depending on the drop-down selection (http://localhost:63968/CreatePDF/GetEmployees/1) and I can use this parameter on the second page as well when I run my application through visual studio.

The problem is after I publish the code to IIS, when I click the link it goes to the url with parameter 1 or 2 (http://localhost/CreatePDF/GetEmployees/1) but it won't display the page. It shows "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." I spend a whole day figuring out the issue and no luck.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check if your project is made to look for port number.

Comment: I'd recommend instead of hard-coding "/CreatePDF/GetEmployees/" in your .attr() statement, get MVC to inject the correct URL using a @Url.Action helper

Comment: @ADyson : I tried to do that first but I don't know how to do that. Then I tried this. Can you show me, please? Thanks

Comment: `$(function () {
        $("#admin").click(function () {
       
            var selectedValue = $("#MyTypes").val();
            
        window.location = "@Url.Action("GetEmployees", "CreatePDF")?type=" + selectedValue;
    });
});`

This doesnt work. The type= is not showing.

Comment: why have you changed the structure of the URL? Before your URL was like "CreatePDF/GetEmployees/1" but now you're doing "CreatePDF/GetEmployees?type=1". Unless you have some custom routing config on the action, then these URLs have two different meanings. Also this appears to be a different section of code than above, so I'm confused how it relates to your original question.

Comment: What I was expecting you to do was change the code in your original question code something like `link.attr("href", @Url.Action("GetEmployees", "CreatePDF") + "/" + selectedValue);`

Comment: Still it doesnt work!

Comment: You mean you still get a 404? What URL is being generated by that code now? Can you show us the code for controller action you're trying to call?